# Group names by ProjectId

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table below where i need to group the names in MS Access query

```
ProjectID  ProjectMgr  PortfolioMgr  
1103       John Smith  
1103                   Jane Doe  
1104       John Smith  
1104                   Tom White
```

I need to ignore the null values and group this as

```
ProjectID ProjectMgr  PortfolioMgr  
1103      John Smith  Jane Doe  
1104      John Smith  Tom White
```

I tried a group query but unsure what to use in the expressions for the two columns.

```
Select ProjectID, ProjectMgr, PortfolioMgr 
from tblProjectAssignment 
group by ProjectID
```

Access gives me the error:

> Your query does not include the specified expression ProjectMgr ,
>   PortfolioMgr as part of an aggregate function.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the query you tried?

Comment: I am bad at sql queries but this is what i got Select ProjectID, ProjectMgr, PortfolioMgr from tblProjectAssignment group by ProjectID. Access gives me the error  "Your query does not include the specified expression ProjectMgr , PortfolioMgr as part of an aggregate function. If you could guide me what I can use as an aggregate function for the names, it will work for me

Comment: @KenWhite I don't see how a union is useful in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use the `MAX()` aggregate:

```
SELECT ProjectID, MAX(ProjectMgr) As Project_Manager,
                  MAX(PortfolioMgr) AS Portfolio_Manager
FROM myTable
GROUP BY ProjectID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try selecting all the distinct project IDs using a `GROUP BY` clause, and then using subqueries to get the project manager and portfolio manager.

```
SELECT a.ProjectID, 
(SELECT s1.ProjectMgr FROM MyTable s1 WHERE s1.ProjectID = a.ProjectID and s1.ProjectMgr Is Not Null) As ProjectMgr, 
(SELECT s2.PortfolioMgr FROM MyTable s2 WHERE s2.ProjectID = a.ProjectID and s2.PortfolioMgr Is Not Null) As PortfolioMgr 
FROM (
   SELECT ProjectID From MyTable GROUP BY ProjectID
) As a
```

You need to replace `MyTable` with your table name

Note that this query will fail when there are multiple project/portfolio managers per ID

Alternatively, you could use joins and join the table with itself 3 times:

```
SELECT a.ProjectID, b.ProjectMgr, c.PortfolioMgr
FROM (SELECT ProjectID From MyTable GROUP BY ProjectID) a
INNER JOIN (SELECT ProjectID, ProjectMgr From MyTable WHERE ProjectMgr Is Not Null) b ON a.ProjectID = b.ProjectID
INNER JOIN (SELECT ProjectID, PortfolioMgr From MyTable WHERE PortfolioMgr Is Not Null) c ON a.ProjectID = c.ProjectID
```

Comment: Thanks Erik, you are always helpful as usual, your second approach worked for me, however the Max aggregate suggested by Parfait looked like a simpler solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code,

```
SELECT a.ProjectID, b.ProjectMgr, c.PortfolioMgr
FROM Your_Table_Name a
INNER JOIN (SELECT ProjectID, ProjectMgr From Your_Table_Name b WHERE ProjectMgr Is Not Null) b ON a.ProjectID = b.ProjectID
INNER JOIN (SELECT ProjectID, PortfolioMgr From Your_Table_Name c WHERE PortfolioMgr Is Not Null) c ON a.ProjectID = c.ProjectID
GROUP BY a.ProjectID
```

Comment: Thanks Abhilash, your approach works but the one suggested by Parfait using the Max aggregate works great